# Definition of natural number

Tags: logic

I'm reading Philosophies of Mathematics by George and Velleman. On p.35 they formally define the natural numbers:
$$
k \text{ is a natural number iff } \forall F[(F0 \wedge \forall x \forall y ((Fx \wedge Sxy) \rightarrow Fy)) \rightarrow Fk].
$$

(Here $S$ denotes the successor relation.)

The immediate question is how we can guarantee that nothing unintended falls under this definition. Regarding this they write

> Following on this, we observe that the adequacy of the definition depends on there being in the range of the second-order quantifier the concept *natural number* itself: the elimination of objects that are not natural numbers depends on this. For instance, why is Julius Caesar not a natural number according to this definition? Only because [...] he does not fall under the concept *natural number* itself.

This looks like circular reasoning ("Julius Caesar is not a natural number because he is not a natural number"), but they continue:

> There is no circularity here: the predicate "natural number" is not used in the definition. Rather, the concept it denotes must be reckoned in the range of the definition's second-order quantifier.

I wonder how to handle the definition of a concept with a quantifier ranging across all concepts ($\forall F$). How is that inevitable self-reference not circular?
Surely the $F$ denoting the concept of being a natural number is indeed the formal one, and not the informal intuitive understanding of a natural number? (Otherwise it would seem that we have gained nothing, and merely defined a natural number using intuitive understanding.) On the other hand, if some $F$ refers to the concept of being a natural number, then how can we claim that "the predicate 'natural number' is not used in the definition"?

Thank you!

Comment: [Second-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic#Models) is *categorical*

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't know how that answers the question. (Note that I have not learned logic other than what's in this book, and had to look 'categorical', 'model' etc. up.)

Comment: nvm I got it now

Comment: See also [How does Frege's definition of number solve the Julius Caesar problem?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41129/how-does-freges-definition-of-number-solve-the-julius-caesar-problem)

Comment: It is [impredicative](https://www.iep.utm.edu/predicat/) but not circular, assuming the "real" existence of objects (included abstract ones, e.g. numbers) and concepts. If so, in full SOL we can quantify over **all** predicates.